# Сделать невозможным заказать товара больше чем он указан в наличии на сайте (Bitrix)

Tags: битрикс

Сайт на Bitrix.
Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли возможность и как реализовать следующий момент -
В карточке указано - в наличии 17 штук. Клиент же может зайти и в корзине выбрать что ему нужно не 17 штук, а 170 например. Можно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы клиент не имел права выбрать количество превышающее имеющееся по факту количество? Чтобы он мог ввести любое значение от 1 до 17, но больше заказать нельзя было ему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну проверяй сколько товара осталось на складе.
У тебя есть ID товара в шаблоне компонента.

```
$storesTable = \Bitrix\Catalog\StoreProductTable::getList([
  'filter' => [
    'PRODUCT_ID' => $arResult['ID']
  ]
])->fetchAll();
```

Ключ ['AMONT'] тебе и выдаст количество товара, доступного к покупке.
Можно передавать это значение в кнопку добавления в корзину и через JS запретить передавать в корзину значение, больше чем есть.